# Voltar à última página

Tags: javascript

Tenho na página (B) o seguinte código para voltar para a última página (A):

```
<div class="return_back" onclick="window.history.go(-1);">< voltar </div>
```

Tenho um formulário na página (B), e se o submeter uma ou mais vezes, ele não retorna para a última página, mas fica na mesma.

Pelo que percebi, o `windows.history` fica algo deste gênero `[A,B,B]`.

É possível resolver isto? Existe possibilidade de ter acesso ao conteúdo do `windows.history`?

Comment: O problema é que a página anterior tem variáveis get no link e são necessárias para depois carregar as infos necessárias

Comment: Mas a submissão envia o formulario para onde ? Qual o `action` do `<form>` ?

Comment: A action do form é a página atual

Comment: Se entendi bem, uma solução seria utilizar ajax para não recarregar a página, assim quando utilizasse o seu botão para voltar, iria voltar para a página A pois não precisaria recarregar a página B a cada submit do formulário.

Answer (score 1):

**Com Javascript**

```
<script>
//Retorna o URI da página que continha o link para a página atual.
var referencia = document.referrer;

//retorna a URL da página atual
var pagina = location.href;

//pegar a parte após o ? (ponto de interrogação
var partes = pagina.toString();
var divide = partes.split("?");
var parametros = divide[1];

//contrução da url da pagina anterior com parametros
var urlVoltar = referencia+"?"+parametros;

//verifica se a sessão está ativa
if ( ! sessionStorage.getItem('voltar')){
    //O objeto Session storage permite aos usuários armazenarem os dados para uma única sessão.
    //A sessão da página dura enquanto o browser está aberto e se mantém no recarregamento da página.
    sessionStorage.setItem("voltar", urlVoltar);
}

var url= sessionStorage.getItem("voltar");

document.write('<div class="return_back" onclick="location.href=\'' + url + '\'">voltar</div>');

</script>
```

[**sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

---

---

**Com PHP**

Com PHP pode resolver isso usando `$_SESSION` e `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ($_SESSION["voltar"]==""){
        $_SESSION["voltar"]=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="return_back" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $_SESSION["voltar"]; ?>'">voltar </div>
```

> `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER` endereço da página através da qual a página atual foi acessada
>
> `$_SESSION` são sessões que permitem salvar dados ($variáveis) durante a visita do cliente